# String array within JSON

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

going mad here, have forgot how to add and array to a JSON object in powershell :/, trying to invoke an API from powershell that requires some parameters one of these is a string array, can someone help?

```
$Children = @("Nanna", "Damian")

$body = @{
'parameters' = @{
  'Name' = 'whatever'
  'Children' = $Children

}
} | ConvertTo-Json
$body
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Body $body -Headers $header -Method Put
```

but it keeps giving me this error :(

Invoke-RestMethod : {"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\"Message\":\"The request is invalid.\",\"ModelState\":{\"job.properties.
parameters.AllowedResourceTypes\":[\"An error has occurred.\"],\"job.properties.parameters.AllowedResourceTypes[0]\":[\"An err
or has occurred.\"]}}"}

believe I have done this before but cant remember how.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Children = @{'Child1'='Nanna'
'Child2'='Damian'}


$body = @{
'parameters' = @{
  'Name' = 'whatever'
  'Children' = $Children

}
} | ConvertTo-Json

$body
```

proper Json

Comment: All you did was change their Array value to an Object value. They had proper JSON already.

Comment: ya but i've noticed that if you use an array when `ConvertTo-Json', i've gotten weird errors, like above.

Comment: I think their issue is syntax, such as submitting a string array when an object is expected, or something like that.